# How to Indicate the Unique Customer ID that not repeated?

Tags: vba, adodb

I have a set of data and I want to create a calculated field in ADODB query that only states a 'unique' against the customer ID that is not repeated more than once.

Would that wok in select statement?

```
IIF(COUNT T1.[Customer ID] <> 1 ,Null ,'Unique') as [Unique]
```

| Customer ID | Unique |
| --- | --- |
| 55850 |  |
| 55850 |  |
| 55850 |  |
| 55850 |  |
| 55850 |  |
| 32336 |  |
| 32336 |  |
| 30131 | Unique |
| 13914 |  |
| 13914 |  |
| 13914 |  |
| 13914 |  |

Comment: What do you mean by "ID that not repeated"? A unique ID cannot be repeated... Is it anything I'm missing? I can see a second column which, supposing that you really need the unique ID, what do you expect as return? Not the unique IDs? Even so, how to be them returned? Do you mean, the ones having **only one occurrence**? As `30131` in the "Customer ID" column? The **existing unique ID**?

Comment: Imagine next to Customer ID a column called Invoice number, So the Customer ID 30131 will have 1 invoice when all the other IDs have more than 1 invoice. so I need the calculated field to indicate the ID that has 1 single invoice as a unique ID(only one occurrence as you said). Make sense?

Comment: Yes, so you need to return in the second column something as in your table. To write Unique (or 1) on the line of the unique ID. Would this understanding be a correct one?

Comment: Yes exactly correct.

Comment: Please, test the answer code I posted and send some feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer to get the result with ADODB, please try.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub ExtractUniqueCustomer()
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strSql As String
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & _
        ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    strSql = " SELECT T1.[Invoice], T1.[Customer ID], IIF(T2.[cnt]=1,'Unique','') FROM [Sheet2$] T1 LEFT JOIN " & _
        " (SELECT [Customer ID], COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM [Sheet2$] GROUP BY [Customer ID] HAVING COUNT(1) = 1) T2 " & _
        " ON T1.[Customer ID]=T2.[Customer ID]"
    rs.Open strSql, conn
    ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlLB9.png]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but you here created Column Unique but it hasn't been used !! I wish if that was listed in the column Unique instead of creating a summary in the range (E2:G10).

Comment: No problem, ADODB can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Please, use the next code. It assumes that the IDs column is A:A.

Using arrays and a dictionary, working mostly in memory, it should be very fast, even for huge range to be processed:

```
Sub UniqueUnique()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, i As Long, dict As Object
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row in A:A
  arr = sh.Range("A2:B" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster processing
  
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
        dict.Add arr(i, 1), i 'place the row where the ID has been found first time
    Else
        dict(arr(i, 1)) = vbNullString 'delete the row number if more than one occurrence
    End If
  Next i
  
  'process the dictionary
  For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
    If dict.Items()(i) <> vbNullString Then arr(dict.Items()(i), 2) = "Unique"
  Next i
  
  'drop back the processed array:
  sh.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2)).Value2 = arr
End Sub
```

Please, test it and send some feedback.

If something not clear, even if I commented each line, please do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Comment: that works well thank you.